# Drawing an image using Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm stuck so I took my code and wrote a smallish example to illustrate my issue.  The texture renders all black.  The target is vkwayland, but I exported my buffers and created vktest to make testing simpler.

Edit: links to sources and renderdocs:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/abp7re/a_smallish_example_of_drawing_an_image_that/ed977in

Validation layers silent.

Much discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/abp7re/a_smallish_example_of_drawing_an_image_that/ed4r5br

Comment: Any errors reported by validation layers?

Comment: @Ekzuzy Validation layers are silent.

Answer (score 0):

So, as resolved on reddit:

You are using obsolete SDK (and Validation layers), therefore you get no error in this case.

And you are reading UINT image format through FLOAT sampler, which yields undefined values (in your case zeroes, i.e. black).